# I am new to xgboost, I get weird results when apply the code to a dataset with values that are below 0 (0.023-0.035....etcetera)

Tags: xgboost

```
parameters = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05],
    'max_depth': [8, 10, 12, 15],
    'gamma': [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02],
    'random_state': [7]
}

eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_valid, y_valid)]
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(eval_set=eval_set, objective='reg:squarederror', verbose=False)
clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image: Weird Feature Importance]

[image: Weird Prediction]